# Can I create a Facebook Album on a secret group from the album that was shared

Tags: facebook

Can I create an album to a facebook secret group (which I belong) from the album that was shared to me from another facebook account?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a link to the other album and post that or you can download all of the photos and re-upload them but otherwise I don't believe you can do a direct share.